QFile создает файл, но не записывает в него данные
Использую Qt 6.7, файл создается, открывается, но не записывает в него, хотя открыт и для чтения, и для записи.
void MainWindow::on_AddAbitur_button_clicked()
{
    QFile file("applicant/myfile.txt");
    file.open(QFile::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text))
        return;
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << "Hello World";
    file.close();
}


а зачем два раза файл открывать?

где вы увидели 2 открытия?

file.open два раза

Разобрался, нужно во флагах форматирования первым флагом указать QIODevice::Append
